# How to call an extension method without using

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class Runner
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        // how to say a.PrintStuff() without a 'using'
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class A { }

namespace ExtensionMethod
{
    static class AExtensions
    {
        public static void PrintStuff(this A a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("text");
        }
    }
}
```

How would I call the extension method without a 'using'? And not ExtensionMethod.AExtensions.PrintStuff(a), since that doesn't make use of extension method.

Comment: Why are you opposed to adding a using statement?

Comment: With your code as is, you can't. Sorry. The c# compiler needs to know where to find the extension method. If it's in a separate namespace, you need the `using`, no way around it.

Comment: I suppose you might be able to call the static extension method manually and pass the object as the first argument, but that would hardly be an improvement over just importing the namespace.

Comment: @BillGregg Just curious if there was a way...

Comment: You can directly call it with `ExtensionMethod.AExtensions.PrintStuff(a)`

Comment: @Lavinski You should add that as an answer.

Comment: OP said that he doesn't want to call it using the fully qualified name unattached to the extended type

Comment: @BillGregg Maybe not OPs intention, but I googled this question since I wanted to call an extension method from VS's Immediate Window.

Comment: @Bill Gregg when you have conflicting names in multiple namespace you cannot rely on `using`.

Answer (score 35):

It is possible to directly call your extension like so since it is simply a static method, passing the instance it will act on as the first `this` parameter:

```
A a = new A();
ExtensionMethod.AExtensions.PrintStuff(a);
```

This might be confusing to other developers who happen across this code if you followed this pattern for more commonly used extension methods.  It would also make chaining extension calls such as LINQ appear more like a functional language because you would be nesting each call instead of chaining them.

Comment: This method works great when you don't want to import a namespace that has lots of collisions with other namespaces that you have already imported.

Comment: You can also use `using static`.

Answer (score 14):

that is possible if Extension Method and class A in same namespace,

If you have to use different namespaces then you have to use `using`, i don't think there is a way to do this without `using`. But you may reduce the number of `using` by putting all the extensions in one namespace like for Linq (`System.Linq.Extensions`)

**Note : You can remove the namespace for Extension methods, then it will make them globally available**

Comment: didn't even know the namespace was not required :)

Answer (score 5):

It needs the `using` to know where the function lives.
One example of this in Linq. Without the System.Linq using - you won't have linq enabled for any of your `IEnumerable<T>'`s

However, you can define the extension method in the same namespace as the caller to avoid putting in a using. This approach will however not work if it's needed in many namespaces

Answer (score 5):

This makes me feel dirty, but you can put your extension methods in the System namespace.
This namespace is included by default in your question

```
using System;

class Runner
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        // how to say a.PrintStuff() without a 'using'
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class A { }

namespace System
{
    static class AExtensions
    {
        public static void PrintStuff(this A a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("text");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of C# v6.0 (circa 2015) you can use [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier) to access a specific class's static members without including it's whole namespace.

An example, using your code, would be:

```
using System;
using static ExtensionMethod.AExtensions;

class Runner
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.PrintStuff();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class A { }

namespace ExtensionMethod
{
    static class AExtensions
    {
        public static void PrintStuff(this A a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("text");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruminations on the creation of extension methods for a type **ExtendableType**:

- Name the class **ExtendableTypeExtensions**
- Declare the extension class **partial** so that clients can add extension methods following the same pattern; and
- Put the extension methods in the same namespace as the base type

*unless* you have a very good reason to follow a model like that of **LINQ**:

- A substantial family of extension methods,
- That all apply to multiple base classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extensions method without namespace. 
This will affect the whole systems which is not recommended.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{       
    public static void HelloWorld(this String s)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello World");
    }
}



    string str = "s";
    str.HelloWorld();
```

Answer (score 0):

In our projects extensions are placed in the same namespace as class extension for. Your example:

```
A.cs:
using System;
namespace ANamespace
{

     class A { }
}

AExtensions.cs:
namespace ANamespace
{
    static class AExtensions
    {
        public static void PrintStuff(this A a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("text");
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you add `using` for ANamespace for using the `A` class, all extensions for `A` class will be included too.